# Laravel 5.4 - MethodNotAllowedHTTPException on DELETE request

Tags: php, laravel, rest

Trying to figure out why my DELETE request not working..I'm using Postman and RESTClient in Firefox to send this DELETE request

DELETE http://localhost:8000/api/access-tokens

and I get the same error :

> (1/1) MethodNotAllowedHttpException
>   in RouteCollection.php (line 252)
>   at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('GET', 'HEAD'))in >RouteCollection.php (line 239)

Here is my routes/api.php:

```
Route::post('access-tokens', 'AuthController@login');

// Register
Route::post('users', 'AuthController@register');

Route::post('recover', 'AuthController@recover');
Route::group(['middleware' => ['jwt.auth']], function() {
Route::delete('access-tokens', 'AuthController@logout');
Route::get('me', function(Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::post('access-tokens/refresh', 'AuthController@refreshToken');
Route::post('ideas', 'IdeasController@store');
```

});

Here is the output of php artisan route:list

```
|        | DELETE   | api/access-tokens            |                      | App\Http\Controllers\AuthController@logout                             | api,jwt.auth |
```

Comment: Probably you have to add a `_token` and a `_method` field to the request. `_method` should have `DELETE` as value.

Comment: use POST method

Comment: I use JWT tokens to authenticate, i'm sending an access token in the Header. I tried adding _method in the Request's Body but no luck!

Comment: I can not use POST method, these are the project's requirements

Comment: move your delete route on top !

Comment: same result ! I noticed that somehow my request is routed to \ but with DELETE method...very strange. I can't find a way to properly debug this problem

Comment: If you want to debug this issue, I suggest to create the same route but instead of `post` or `delete`, use `any` and check the request method inside your controller.

Comment: Thank you for your help! The problem was in my controller , I don't understand why but commenting a line solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my controller..commented one line and it works!
Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

You are posting your data as GET, try add method field

```
{{ method_field('DELETE') }}
```

Comment: I don't think so..if you read my sentences, you'd noticed i am doing a DELETE request with postman..no FORM here